# how to solve nonlinear coupled partial differential system

Tags: pde

I have to solve the following nonlinear coupled partial differential system ([link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cyptnzxj6mvxkt/system.png)). All the functions are better explained [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2dsbqgfvq1g1zj/fun.png).

Even if I use the **finite difference method** (i.e. central difference in space and forward Crank-Nicholson in time in order to obtain an implicit scheme) I don't know how to linearize the problem (I have to solve a nonlinear system: I tried using Newton method, but sometimes I get a singular Jacobian; moreover, the function tau(lambda) is a non-convex energy, so I'm near a spinoidal point). Could you suggest some method?

Thanks in advance for all your help.
Petrus

Comment: Haha, awesome!  I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Probably better asked on the [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: You sure this doesn't belong in Mathematics or something?